# Why application stops for some time and button also not pushed

Tags: android

This is a gist of my program.When I pressed the button for telling the location it works fine if geocoder does not throw any exception, but the problem comes when the geocoder throws exception and at the same time my application stop for some time it just like it hangs.

Because progress bar stop rotating, and the stop button also not pressed.But after 30 seconds or 1 min it prints:

> no address found…

Can anybody help me to separate out this problem… Thank You in advance.

This is in onCreate Method:

```
 locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,3, this);
```

//Separate Method:

```
public void geo(double latitude,double longitude)
    {

        if(Geocoder.isPresent())
        {

            try 
            {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
         List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0)
            {
                 Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

            }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Searching..",dur).show();
        }

        } 

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this,Location, dur).show();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No address found",dur).show();
        }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"wait...",dur).show();
        }
    }
```

This geo method called in onLocationChanged method after getting the latitude and longitude, to getting the location.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is in the geocoder's attempts to get your location (maybe it's just waiting for response from the sensors or network). You should execute request to the geocoder in a separate thread to prevent hanging (you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for it). But be noticed that all work with UI, like showing toasts, have to be done in the main UI thread (you can use method [runOnUiThread from Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) )

Comment: According to you I have put my whole code of reverse geocoding in the asynctask and fortunately the problem is solved, but the second occur problem is that when I called class Double[] lat_long = new Double[] { latitude, longitude};
        new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latlong); in onLocationChanged() method, it was not called again means its not  updating...Please tell what should I do now...Thank you..

Comment: May I have more details? Is it called at first time in onLocationChanged and is it possible to see updated code?

Comment: public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) 
 {
  if(location!=null)
  {
  double longitude = location.getLongitude();
  double latitude = location.getLatitude();
  Double[] lat_long = new Double[] { latitude, longitude};
   
        new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(lat_long);
  //geo(latitude,longitude);
  }
  else
  {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wait...",dur).show();
  }
 }
 //This is in onLocationChanged() method

Comment: try {
             listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);
      if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0)
      {Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);                 
      }
            }catch (Exception e)     {}   //This is in protected String doInBackground(Double... params). In post excecute I have print this location but now when i run this in bluestack it tells me location but in mobile its not showing any location even with full network and also having gps...I don't know what is going on...

Comment: Sorry, I can't recognize the problem. If it works on emulator but doesn't work on mobile you should seek for any exceptions in logcat or some configuration issues. And try to debug

Comment: It's Ok...Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Location Service you instantiate collecting information on position every 1 second, and would be a good practice using this service not in UI Thread but in a service or a thread, and is a good practice following these steps:

> Defining a Model for the Best Performance
>   Location-based applications are now commonplace, but due to the less than optimal accuracy, user movement, the multitude of methods to obtain the location, and the desire to conserve battery, getting user location is complicated. To overcome the obstacles of obtaining a good user location while preserving battery power, you must define a consistent model that specifies how your application obtains the user location. This model includes when you start and stop listening for updates and when to use cached location data.
>
> Flow for obtaining user location
>
> Here's the typical flow of procedures for obtaining the user location:
>
> 1. Start application. 2. Sometime later, start listening for updates from
>      desired location providers. 3. Maintain a "current best estimate" of
>      location by filtering out new, but less accurate fixes. 4. Stop listening
>      for location updates. 4. Take advantage of the last best location
>      estimate.